# Android connectivity with MySql using jsp

Tags: java, android, jsp

I am developing a web app in JSP. For same project I'm developing an Android app. The web app uses Apache Tomcat and MySQL. Now I want to make registration form and login form of the Android application that interface with same MySQL database. But how?

I did find many tutorials but all are using PHP scripts. I'm using Eclipse for web development and Android Studio for android app.

Answer (score 0):

This will involve at least 4 steps

1. Create a POJO that will represent your data.

   ```
   public class LoginData implements Serializable{

   public String loginName;
   public String loginPassword;
   //all other attributes that you need to send over HTTP
   }
   ```
2. Create s simple HTTP client (either using Java API, Apache HTTP client or some other library). My example is using Apache

   //you only need 1 client so make it static

   ```
   public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient(int timeout) {

    DefaultHttpClient client = null;
    SchemeRegistry Current_Scheme = new SchemeRegistry();
    Current_Scheme.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    HttpParams Current_Params = new BasicHttpParams();
    //set initial params
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(Current_Params, timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(Current_Params, timeout);
    ThreadSafeClientConnManager Current_Manager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(Current_Params, Current_Scheme);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(Current_Manager, Current_Params);
    return client;
   }
   ```
3. In order to send your POJO, you should first serialize it (the first argument is Object so that it can accept any type, not just LoginData)
   //The data will be formatted as application/x-www-form in this way (BTW, web apps use this by default)

   ```
   HttpEntity serializePOJO(Object o,String encoding)
   List<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   Map<String, Object> maps=objectMapper.convertValue(o, Map.class);
   Set<String> keys=maps.keySet();
   Iterator<String> itr=keys.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
       String key=itr.next();
       Object value=maps.get(key);
       if(value!=null){
           postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, value.toString()));
       }
   }
   UrlEncodedFormEntity data=null;
   try {
       data = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams,encoding);//e.g.UTF-8

   } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       throw e;
   }
   return data;
   ```

   }
4. Issue a HTTP request

   ```
   public void checkLogin(LoginData data)throws Exception 
   {
    String url = "localhost:8080/myApp/login";
    HttpPost request=null;
    try{
       request=new HttpPost(url);
       request.setEntity(serializePOJO(data));

       HttpResponse response=getHttpClient(10000).execute(hg);
       if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()!=200){
           //handle exception
       }
   }finally{
       if(request!=null){
           request.releaseConnection();
       }
   }
   }
   ```

You can initialize objectMapper as

```
    objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Your servlet should connect to the database and do all the processing , not the JSP page.

Comment: But how to make sign up form of android app connected with MySql workbench?